# Is Reflection a nested namespace inside System namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces, system

I was wondering why we need to specify **using System.Reflection** separately from **using System** while making use of methods in class **Type**. Is Reflection a nested namespace, inside System namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, System.Reflection is a namespace inside the System namespace.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481557(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using **System** namespace does not include all child namespaces.

Here, System.Reflection is a child namespace of System.So you have to import it explicitly by **using** directive.

**Note**:Same principle applies to all namespace in c# for example System and System.IO and many more.